# 'difficult' Determine proximity between 2 strings in python

Tags: python, algorithm, proximity

I have 2 strings `loss of gene` and `aquaporin protein`. In a line, I want to find if these two exist in a line of my file, within a proximity of 5 words. 
Any ideas? I have searched extensively but cannot find anything. 
Also, since these are multi-word strings, I cannot use abs(array.index) for the two (which was possible with single words).

Thanks

Comment: Please give an example of the so called `proximity`...

Comment: @Sayakiss by proximity, I mean if these two lie close to each other, say 5 words apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following approach:

1. First sanitise your text by converting it to lowercase, keeping only the characters and enforcing one space between each word.
2. Next, search for each of the phrases in the resulting text and keep a note of the starting index and the length of the phrase matched. Sort this index list.
3. Next make sure that all of the phrases were present in the text by making sure all found indexes are not `-1`.
4. If all are found count the number of words between the end of the first phrase, and the start of the last phrase. To do this take a text slice starting from the end of the first phrase to the start of the second phrase, and split it into words.

Script as follows:

```
import re

text = "The  Aquaporin protein, sometimes  'may' exhibit a big LOSS of gene."
text = ' '.join(re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b', text.lower()))

indexes = sorted((text.find(x), len(x)) for x in ['loss of gene', 'aquaporin protein'])

if all(i[0] != -1 for i in indexes) and len(text[indexes[0][0] + indexes[0][1] : indexes[-1][0]].split()) <= 5:
    print "matched"
```

To extend this to work on a file with a list of phrases, the following approach could be used:

```
import re

log = 'loss of gene'
phrases = ['aquaporin protein', 'another protein']

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for number, line in enumerate(f_input, start=1):
        # Sanitise the line
        text = ' '.join(re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\b', line.lower()))

        # Only process lines containing 'loss of gene'
        log_index = text.find(log)

        if log_index != -1:
            for phrase in phrases:
                phrase_index = text.find(phrase)

                if phrase_index != -1:
                    if log_index < phrase_index:
                        start, end = (log_index + len(log), phrase_index)
                    else:
                        start, end = (phrase_index + len(phrase), log_index)

                    if len(text[start:end].split()) <= 5:
                        print "line {} matched - {}".format(number, phrase)
                        break
```

This would give you the following kind of output:

```
line 1 matched - aquaporin protein
line 5 matched - another protein
```

Note, this will only spot one phrase pair per line.

Comment: thanks Martin. could you explain what are indexes[0][1], indexes[-1][0] and indexes[0][0]  ?

Comment: If you `print indexes`, you will see a list of tuples. The first is the index, the second is the length, so `indexes[0][1]` is the length of the first entry. `-1` is the last entry (I could have used `1` as there are only two).

Comment: thanks again. Also, as I pointed out in my comment to the previous answer, `aquaporin protein` is actually an element of a list containing 300,000 such strings; all of which are to be checked for. So, don't you think I should first check if my line has `loss of gene` to eliminate lines not having it and then do what you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure if this is what you want, but I'll give it a shot!

In Python, you can use "in" to check if a string is in another string. I am going to assume you already have a way to store a line from a file:

```
"loss of gene" in fileLine -> returns boolean (either True or False)
```

With this you can check if "loss of gene" and "aquaporin protein" are in your line from your file. Once you have confirmed that they are both there you can check their proximity by splitting the line of text into a list as so:

```
wordsList = fileLine.split()
```

If in your text file you have the string:

> "The aquaporin protein sometimes may exhibit a loss of gene"

After splitting it becomes:

```
["The","aquaporin","protein","sometimes","may","exhibit","a","loss","of","gene"]
```

I'm not sure if that is a valid sentence but for the sake of example let's ignore it :P

Once you have the line of text split into a list of words and confirmed the words are in there, you can get their proximity with the index function that comes with lists in python!

```
wordsList.index("protein") -> returns index 2
```

After finding what index "protein" is at you can check what index "loss" is at, then subtract them to find out if they are within a 5 word proximity.

You can use the index function to discern if "loss of gene" comes before or after "aquaporin protein". If "loss of gene" comes first, index "gene" and "aquaporin" and subtract those indexes. If "aquaporin protein" comes first, index "protein" and "loss" and subtract those indexes.

You will have to do a bit more to ensure that you subtract indexes correctly if the words come in different orders, but this should cover the meat of the problem. Good luck Chahat!

Comment: thanks a lot! this is pretty good. Let me just see if someone has any other suggestions!

Comment: Should you take care to not delimit by `\n` and possibly use some punctuation as a delimiter for `.split()`?  If delimiting by `\n` you may split sentences/lines that would hold a match.  Depending on how the file is written.

Comment: hey, i also wanted to ask that actually `aquaporin protein` was not a one-off string. Its a part of a file having 300,000 more such strings. So should I first check if any of the 300K strings are in the line?

Comment: Yes. I am not too well versed with how you could do that efficiently but I think its doable.